# Database connection in eclipse - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, jdbc

I have created connection profile of MySQL in Eclipse.I have written this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1";
            conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","swathi");

            Statement stmt= conn.createStatement();
            String query="select * from sample";

            System.out.println(stmt.executeQuery(query));

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

i have set the

```
classpath=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
```

When i run the program i am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C:\Users\swathi\workspace\project1;C:\Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\Users\swathi\workspace\project1;C:\Program
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to extend your project's class path is to edit the setting for that project:

```
Right click on your project > Build Path > Configure Build Path...
```

Go to the tab `Libraries` then

click `Add External JARs...`, locate the jdbc driver and click `open` then `OK`.

Or

click `Add Library...` then `User Library` and ckick `Next >`. Click `User Libraries` and then click `New...`. enter a name for your lib, for example `JDBC_DRIVER_MYSQL_5` then click `Add External JARs...`.

I would recomend though to convert your project into a [maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) project and add it as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that your `classpath` contains spaces. Try to quote it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of doing

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;JAVA_HOME\lib;
```

Just add `mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar`: to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Eclipse is smart enough to recognize .jar files added under `/WEB-INF/lib` and should include in the `CLASSPATH`.