# Importing jdom to eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, import, jdom

I am trying to use the jdom 2.0.5 library and I have gone through the steps of importing it and configuring the build path but when I attempt to import the libraries I get an error saying "the import cannot be resolved"

Comment: You are using `import org.jdom2. ...` and not `org.jdom. ...`, right? CHeck this page out: https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-Migration-Issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "the import cannot be resolved"

means either you have a misspelling somewhere in the import directive or you haven't configured the build path correctly. If you have, then after using a jdom Class in your code organize the import using `Ctrl-Shift+o`. If you haven't then configure your class path correctly by one of the following methods:

1. Download  [jdom2](http://www.jdom.org/downloads/) jars and save them somewhere. Configure your build path as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19834510/1113392).
2. Convert your project to a [maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) project and add the following dependency in the [pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) file:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
       <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.5</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: THANKS!! Fixed it. Build path was messed up. Forgot to extract the .zip folder -_-

Comment: @user2974665, You're welcome! You may want to accept the answer if helped you. Otherweise I would strongly recomend you to have a look at maven: [getting started guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)